# Clarification on vulnerability statuses

Tags: ubuntu, cve, debian

What do statuses of Ubuntu and Debian security trackers mean exactly in plain of definitely vulnerable\definitely not vulnerable\unknown?

I have found this answer [How to read CVE - 2016 - 5696 correctly](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134269/how-to-read-cve-2016-5696-correctly?newreg=97d9077f4c7d4180b93488c32398a2b0) about ubuntu tracker, but its missing the "deferred" status.

I could not find any documentation about any statuses of debian security tracker.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I googled "ubuntu cve status meaning" and got https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/BugTriage .

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2019-14899
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-3715
deferred
end of life
ignored
does not exist
needed;
same for debian
https://github.com/aquasecurity/vuln-list/blob/main/debian/CVE/CVE-2020-6497.json
https://github.com/aquasecurity/vuln-list/blob/main/debian/CVE/CVE-2009-0065.json
https://github.com/aquasecurity/vuln-list/blob/main/debian/CVE/CVE-2021-30474.json
https://github.com/aquasecurity/vuln-list/blob/main/debian/CVE/CVE-2022-1050.json

end of life
removed
no-dsa
postponed;
triage docs that you linked seem to be something different.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in a README from the link that schroeder referenced

```
deferred    The package (for the given release) is vulnerable, the problem
        is understood, but has been deferred for some reason. The
        "notes" need to explain further. If a date was specified eg
        "deferred (2012-01-01)" the date indicates the date the CVE
        was put in the deferred state.
```

https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cve-tracker/tree/README#n199